# I uploaded my website and on of the tabs is in chinese

Tags: html, css

I uploaded my website and one of the tab(more info) is in chinese for some reason and I dont know why. here is the the url http://bushdid911.net

http://pastebin.com/jFBUV1ga

Comment: Those damn Chinese! It's bad enough they hack the US Government, now they're hacking this poor kids conspiracy site!

Answer (score 3):

At very least, you should add

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

to the html's `<head>` section.

A (very, very) basic html template you should use is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Page title</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Another reason could be that Bush did this, too. Just to create another conspiracy theory..

Comment: You forgot the `</bush>` tag.